# GetTokenInformation, TOKEN_OWNER, и LookupAccountSidA

Tags: c, winapi

Пытаюсь с помощью этих функций получить имя пользователя запустившего процесс.

Вот код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
using namespace std;

int main()    
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    HANDLE hToken;
    OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    DWORD len = 0;
    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, 0, &len);

    PTOKEN_OWNER to = (PTOKEN_OWNER)LocalAlloc(LPTR, len);
    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, (LPVOID)&to, len, &len);

    char nameUser[50];
    DWORD nameUserSize = sizeof(nameUser);
    SID_NAME_USE snu;
    cout << "work";
    LookupAccountSidA(NULL, to->Owner, nameUser, &nameUserSize, NULL, NULL, &snu);

    cout << "not work";
    cout << nameUser << endl;
    LocalFree(to);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

У меня все крашится на моменте, где вызывается функция `LookupAccountSidA`. Но я подозреваю что это из-за того, что я неправильно либо передаю аргументы в эту функцию, либо я неправильно создаю структуру `TOKEN_OWNER`. Причем второй вариант более вероятен, так как я не понимаю как здесь выделяется память.

Я взял пример с MSDN и переделал под свои потребности, но ничего не работает. Вот примеры с MSDN:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446670(v=vs.85).aspx,
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379554(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если во время выполнения функции, входящей в состав WinAPI, происходит аварийное завершение работы программы, значит, внутри неё происходит обращение по некорректному или нулевому указателю.

Смотрим, как именно вызывается функция:

```
LookupAccountSidA(NULL, to->Owner, nameUser, &nameUserSize, NULL, NULL, &snu);
```

Видим передачу трёх нулевых указателей. Смотрим в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa379166(v=vs.85).aspx), можно ли так делать:

- *`lpSystemName [in, optional]`* — параметр необязателен (`optional`), значит можно.
- *`lpReferencedDomainName [out, optional]`* — аналогично.
- *`cchReferencedDomainName [in, out]`* — а вот сюда `NULL` передавать нельзя.

Попробуйте передать в `cchReferencedDomainName` указатель на локальную переменную типа `DWORD`, инициализированную нулём.

---

*По результатам обсуждения в комментариях было внесено следующее дополнение:*

Оказывается, этого мало. Буфер для принятия имени группы (`lpReferencedDomainName`) также должен быть задан и иметь достаточный размер. В противном случае возвращаемое имя пользователя будет равно `@`.

Рабочий пример, выводящий у меня `Олег\FAMILYPC`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    HANDLE hToken;
    OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    DWORD len = 0;
    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, 0, &len);

    PTOKEN_OWNER to = (PTOKEN_OWNER)LocalAlloc(LPTR, len);
    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, to, len, &len);

    char userName[50];
    char domainName[50];
    DWORD userNameSize = sizeof(userName);
    DWORD domainNameSize = sizeof(domainName);

    SID_NAME_USE snu;
    LookupAccountSidA(NULL, to->Owner, userName, &userNameSize, domainName, &domainNameSize, &snu);
    std::cout << userName << "\\" << domainName << std::endl;

    LocalFree(to);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Передал. Не помогло. Здесь проблема не в этом параметре, а скорее всего во втором. Вы мне лучше объясните, как происходит  выделение памяти в этих строках(взято из примера 2):
pGroupInfo = (PTOKEN_GROUPS) GlobalAlloc( GPTR, dwSize );
Я переделал под свое, делал через GlobalAlloc и через LocalAlloc. Все ломается.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я передаю в функцию GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, (LPVOID)&to, len, &len); третим параметром адрес указателя, а нужно просто (LPVOID)to. Теперь программа выполняется, но все равно не так как надо. Выводит символ "@" вместо имени пользователя.

Comment: @van9petryk, проблему устранил; смотрите дополнение к ответу.

Comment: Ну да, уже лучше. Только у меня выводится не Ivan\IvanPc, а Администраторы\BUILTIN

Comment: @van9petryk, значит, программа или среда разработки (права наследуются, упрощённо говоря, от запускающих программ к запускаемым) запущена от имени администратора.

Comment: @van9petryk: `... так как я не понимаю как здесь выделяется память.` — ответ оформил в виде отдельного вопроса (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521737/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-token-owner-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5/521738), так как тема достаточно объёмная.