# Создание структуры TOKEN_OWNER на стеке

Tags: c, winapi

Здравствуйте!

Почему во всех примерах по использованию функции `GetTokenInformation`, включая [пример с MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379554(v=vs.85).aspx), для токена используется тип данных указателя `PTOKEN_OWNER`? Что мешает создавать экземпляр `TOKEN_OWNER` (без начальной «P») прямо на стеке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поидее, на этот вопрос можно было бы просто ответить: «Память выделяется в куче» и успокоиться на этом. Однако мне стало интересно, а почему во всех примерах, связанных с токеном безопасности, фигурирует пара `PTOKEN_*`—`GlobalAlloc`. Почему нельзя просто создать локальную переменную типа `TOKEN_*`?

Вопрос оказался сложнее, чем может показаться на первый взгляд, а потому и ответ на него стал достаточно большим. По сути, был рассмотрен не один, а три взаимосвязанных вопроса, каждому из которых уделён свой раздел ответа.

---

### 1. Зачем выделять память

Поговорим о необходимости динамического выделения памяти для токена. Казалось бы, чего такого сложного может быть в бесхитростной структуре [`TOKEN_OWNER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379628(v=vs.85).aspx)? Вроде ничего особенного — знай себе, создавай локальную переменную да передавай указатель на неё в функцию `GetTokenInformation`:

```
// ...

TOKEN_OWNER to;
DWORD len = sizeof(to);
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, &to, len, &len);

// ...
```

Однако программа с таким фрагментом в лучшем случае возвращает весьма странные результаты, а в худшем — аварийно завершает свою работу. В чём же дело?

Подвох заключается в том, что `TOKEN_OWNER` — это структура с «двойным дном». С одной стороны, она содержит поле-указатель на SID (идентификатор безопасности), а с другой — какие-то дополнительные, скрытые поля, в которых операционная система хранит внутреннюю, недоступную для прямого чтения и изменения информацию.

Для простоты понимания можно представить себе, что `TOKEN_OWNER` — это базовый класс, предоставляемый программисту, а сама Windows оперирует неким дочерним классом, унаследованным от `TOKEN_OWNER`.

Самое странное, что данная особенность не описана *нигде*. Хотя о поле-указателе `TOKEN_OWNER::Owner` MSDN честно говорит [следующее](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379594(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The security identifier (SID) structure is a variable-length structure used to uniquely identify users or groups.

В переводе:

> Идентификатор безопасности (SID) — это **структура переменной длины**, используемая для однозначной идентификации пользователя или группы.

Из всего вышеописанного можно сделать ряд важных выводов:

1. Точное строение структуры `TOKEN_OWNER` неизвестно. Нам просто дают указатель на единственное известное поле `Owner`, а остальное предлагают рассматривать как «чёрный ящик».
2. Скрытые поля не являются частью официального API, а следовательно, их состав и назначение может меняться между версиями Windows при введении новых аспектов безопасности. Как результат, даже если мы и узнаем, что именно хранится в скрытой части, прямое обращение к этим полям чревато неработоспособностью нашей программы в будущем.
3. Раз полный вариант структуры известен исключительно операционной системе, то и размер памяти, необходимый для её размещения необходимо узнавать у той же операционной системы. За получение размера отвечает строка `GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, 0, &len);`, где происходит:

   - передача пустого буфера,
   - игнорирование ошибки `GetLastError() == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL`, то есть ошибки о недостаточности размера переданного буфера
   - и наконец, получение минимально необходимого размера буфера в переменную `len` (потому мы и передаём эту переменную по указателю, чтобы функция заполнила её для нас).
4. Если размер структуры заранее (то есть на этапе компиляции) неизвестен, то мы вынуждены выделять память под неё в куче. Мы бы могли с таким же успехом воспользоваться функцией `alloca`, динамически выделяющей память на стеке, но она не входит в стандарт, а потому может отсутствовать у некоторых компиляторов.

Именно поэтому мы вынуждены заменить

```
TOKEN_OWNER to;
DWORD len = sizeof(to);
```

на

```
DWORD len = 0;
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, 0, &len);
PTOKEN_OWNER to = (PTOKEN_OWNER)LocalAlloc(LPTR, len);
```

где `PTOKEN_OWNER` определён как `typedef struct TOKEN_OWNER* PTOKEN_OWNER;`.

---

### 2. Почему именно LocalAlloc

Теперь может возникнуть вопрос, почему же именно `LocalAlloc`? Чем плохи `GlobalAlloc`, `HeapAlloc`, да, в конце концов, `malloc` и `new`? Ведь все пять функций выделяют место в куче текущего процесса и возвращают на него одинаковый указатель.

Эм... Не совсем. Точнее, *когда-то* было не совсем.

Дело в том, что в 16-битную эпоху (Windows 1.0–Me) виртуальная память либо ещё не была изобретена (Windows 1.0–2.11), либо могла не применяться (Windows 3.0–Me). *[Информация взята из статьи Центра поддержки Windows «[Windows Version History](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/32905)»]*.

Как же 16-битная Windows могла поддерживать многозадачность, если в отсутствие виртуальной памяти все программы размещались в одном адресном пространстве, общий размер которого не может превышать 2<sup>16</sup>=64KB? И это ещё без учёта вычетов на нужды операционной системы и оборудования.

Эм... И снова, не совсем 64 килобайта. На счастье программистов тех лет существовало такое понятие, как сегментация — разбиение памяти на участки, адресация внутри которых была непрерывной и производилась силами 16-битного, *ближнего* указателя. Вот размер сегмента, то есть участка *непосредственно* адресуемой ближним указателем памяти, и был равен 64KB. Межсегментные же обращения выполнялись с помощью расширенного, *дальнего* указателя, содержащего в себе помимо линейного адреса ещё и номер сегмента. Такие дальние обращения обходились дороже (особенно с учётом загрузки-выгрузки сегментов Windows-ом, о чём можно почитать у Реймонда Чена в статье «[What happened in real-mode Windows when somebody did a longjmp into a discardable segment?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140103-00/?p=2173)» и на Хабрахабре в статье «[Управление памятью в реальном режиме Windows](https://habrahabr.ru/post/154713/)»).

Windows делила сегменты на два вида — *частные*, которые целиком относятся к тому или иному приложению или библиотеке, и *общие*, разделяемые между всеми приложениями сразу. Соответственно, существовало и два вида куч: частные, доступные через `LocalAlloc` (возвращавшую ближний указатель), и глобальные, доступные через `GlobalAlloc` (возвращавшую дальний указатель). И если для внутренних данных приложения могла использоваться любая из них, то обмен данными с другими приложениями и функциями операционной системы должен был проходить исключительно через глобальную кучу. Именно поэтому во всех примерах работы с функциями из Windows API используется `GlobalAlloc` при динамическом выделении памяти.

Сейчас же это не имеет никакого смысла, поскольку сегменты были упразднены, 32-битные приложения получили полный 32-битный же указатель, а `GlobalAlloc` и `LocalAlloc` стали заглушками над нововведённой `HeapAlloc`, ровно как и `malloc` и `new`.

---

### 3. Что скрывается внутри структуры TOKEN_OWNER

Итак, мы выяснили, почему получение токена безопасности сопряжено с обязательным выделением памяти в куче. Заодно мы выяснили, что структура `TOKEN_OWNER` содержит какие-то дополнительные данные, скрытые от глаз программиста.

Зачем так было сделано? И что там может скрываться? На первый вопрос мы, будучи некомпетентными в информационной безопасности, не можем дать ответа. Однако на второй ответ дать ответ уже вполне можно. Дело в том, что в настоящее время имеются две открытые реализации Windows API, направленные на обеспечение максимальной совместимости с оригиналом. Это *Wine* (рассматриваемая ниже) и *ReactOS API*.

*Перед дальнейшим изложением повторюсь:*

> *Скрытые поля не являются частью официального API, а следовательно, их состав и назначение может меняться между версиями Windows.*

*Всё нижесказанное предназначено **исключительно для удовлетворения любопытства** и верно для одной конкретной реализации. Автор не несёт ответственности за порчу данных и/или уязвимости, возникшие вследствие использования недокументированных возможностей Windows API.*

Почему мы вообще решили, что в структуре записано что-то дополнительное? Дело в том, что размер буфера, требуемый для хранения структуры `TOKEN_OWNER`, составляет ни много ни мало 32 байта (актуально для подсистемы WoW x32 в Windows 7 SP1):

```
DWORD len = 0;
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, 0, &len);
std::cout << len << std::endl; // Выводит «32».
```

хотя размер поля-указателя `TOKEN_OWNER::Owner` всего 4 байта. Разница между этими двумя величинами, 28 байт, и составляет размер дополнительных данных.

Итак, поехали. Для начала рассмотрим [реализацию функции `GetTokenInformation`](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/advapi32/security.c#0729), вызываемой из кода в вопросе:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetTokenInformation(...)
{
    TRACE(...);
    return set_ntstatus( NtQueryInformationToken( token, tokeninfoclass, tokeninfo,
                                                  tokeninfolength, retlen));
}
```

То есть это просто обёртка над `NtQueryInformationToken`. Идём [дальше](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ntdll/nt.c#0235). Код функции длинный, а потому рассмотрим лишь необходимые куски:

```
NTSTATUS WINAPI NtQueryInformationToken(...)
{
    static const ULONG info_len [] = {
        ...
        0,    /* TokenOwner */
        ...
    };

    ULONG len = 0;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    TRACE(...);

    if (tokeninfoclass < MaxTokenInfoClass)
        len = info_len[tokeninfoclass];

    if (retlen) *retlen = len;

    if (tokeninfolength < len)
        return STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL;

    switch (tokeninfoclass)
    {
    ...
    case TokenOwner:
        SERVER_START_REQ( get_token_sid )
        {
            TOKEN_OWNER *towner = tokeninfo;
            PSID sid = towner + 1;
            DWORD sid_len = tokeninfolength < sizeof(TOKEN_OWNER) ? 0 : tokeninfolength - sizeof(TOKEN_OWNER);

            req->handle = wine_server_obj_handle( token );
            req->which_sid = tokeninfoclass;
            wine_server_set_reply( req, sid, sid_len );
            status = wine_server_call( req );
            if (retlen) *retlen = reply->sid_len + sizeof(TOKEN_OWNER);
            if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                towner->Owner = sid;
        }
        SERVER_END_REQ;
        break;
    ...
}
return status;
```

Что же мы имеем? *Wine* (а точнее реализованная в нём функция `NtQueryInformationToken`) рассматривает `PTOKEN_OWNER` как указатель на структуру следующего вида:

```
TOKEN_OWNER
{
    PSID* Owner ---+
}                  |
SID     <----------+
{
    ...
}
```

где `TOKEN_OWNER` адресуется локальной переменной `towner` (`TOKEN_OWNER *towner = tokeninfo;`), а `SID` — локальной переменной `sid` (`PSID sid = towner + 1;`).

То есть «скрытая» часть — это всего лишь то, на что указывает поле `TOKEN_OWNER::Owner`. Иными словами, всё связанное с токеном собрано в одном месте.